# FInd out how many days in the future a datetime is

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have this DateTime object:

```
model.Model.Results.FloatingComponent().Schedule.ScheduleRows[0].Payment.FromDate.AdjustedDate
```

How do I find out how many days into the future that is, if it is in the future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
TimeSpan delta = Foo.AdjustedDate - DateTime.Now;

if(delta.Days > 0)
{
  //...
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on @Gabe's comment here a version that only looks at the days:

```
TimeSpan delta = Foo.AdjustedDate.Date - DateTime.Today;

if(delta.Days > 0)
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: i was typing.. u beat me to it

Comment: I would use `Today` instead of `Now` in case the times don't match up properly.

Comment: @Gabe - you could argue both ways, I don't know how the OP wants to handle fractional days

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime mydate = ....

TimeSpan span = mydate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

// then use span.Days;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int days = (futureDate - DateTime.Today).Days;
```